# i want to link all of these tables (student , teacher , courses) to parent table (classes) but i have error?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
 CREATE TABLE student 
 (
 s_id INTEGER  ,
 s_name VARCHAR2(80) ,
 s_email VARCHAR (80) ,
 FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES classes (s_id)
 );
 CREATE TABLE teacher 
 (
 t_id INTEGER ,
 t_name VARCHAR2(80) ,
 t_email VARCHAR2 (80) ,
 FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES classes (t_id)
 );
 CREATE TABLE courses
 (
 c_id INTEGER  ,
 c_title VARCHAR2 (25) ,
 c_describetion VARCHAR2 (25) ,
 FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES classes (c_id)
 );
 CREATE TABLE classes
 (
 cl_name VARCHAR2 (30) ,
 cl_number INTEGER ,
 t_id INTEGER ,
 s_id INTEGER ,
 c_id INTEGER ,
 PRIMARY KEY (cl_number , t_id , s_id , c_id)
 );
```

- when i need to create these tables (student , teacher , courses) i have this Error :
  Error report -
  ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

  2270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
        *Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
        *Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the table "classes" from the other three. It's classes the one that should reference those. Put the FK in the columns of classes referencing the "id" field of the corresponding table. Also, I think you will need to define them as PK/UNIQUE.

Comment: Oh , thank you man you are solving my problem i love you so much .

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the foreign keys the other way around. You want `classes` to have foreign keys that reference the other tables. You also need to define primary keys in the 3 master tables, so they can be referenced as foreign key.

Also, there is no `VARCHAR2` datatype in MySQL (this is an Oracle-specific datatype): use `VARCHAR  instead.

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    s_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    s_name VARCHAR(80),
    s_email VARCHAR(80)
);

CREATE TABLE teacher (
    t_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    t_name VARCHAR(80),
    t_email VARCHAR(80) 
);

CREATE TABLE courses (
     c_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     c_title VARCHAR(25),
     c_description VARCHAR(25) 
);

 CREATE TABLE classes (
     cl_name VARCHAR(30),
     cl_number INTEGER,
     t_id INTEGER,
     s_id INTEGER,
     c_id INTEGER,
     PRIMARY KEY (cl_number , t_id , s_id , c_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES student (s_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES teacher (t_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES courses (c_id)
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1678f116a4e4bc336707e5a1b1a00f3)**

---

If you are running Oracle (like the error message in your question indicates) rather than MySQL (which you tagged your question) with, then you want `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR` (which is deprecated). The rest of the script remains the same:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    s_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    s_name VARCHAR2(80),
    s_email VARCHAR2(80)
);

CREATE TABLE teacher (
    t_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    t_name VARCHAR2(80),
    t_email VARCHAR2(80) 
);

CREATE TABLE courses (
     c_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     c_title VARCHAR2(25),
     c_description VARCHAR2(25) 
);

 CREATE TABLE classes (
     cl_name VARCHAR2(30),
     cl_number INTEGER,
     t_id INTEGER,
     s_id INTEGER,
     c_id INTEGER,
     PRIMARY KEY (cl_number , t_id , s_id , c_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES student (s_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES teacher (t_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES courses (c_id)
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=49b1f1071e930e0fab8b560cde50a985)**

Comment: Isn't it an Oracle DB?

Comment: @nimsraw: ah yes, you are probably right, since there is an `ORA-` error message in the question. I edited my answer accordingly. Thank you.